# Get logged in user name in maven custom archetype

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

What is the system property like ${user} that I can use to get the name of the user who has generated the project using my custom maven archetype, similar to using placeholders like ${package}, ${artifactId} ? I want to use this value in one of the properties file of the generated project.

From what I found in online sources, tried the following but nothing works 
${user}, ${user.name}, ${username} and ${ENV.user}

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "user"? The active user in the operating system?

Comment: Yes the active user in OS who is in my case also the user who has run the mvn archetype:generate  command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <echoproperties />
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

to get the available properties printed to the console.

Comment: I want to replace some placeholders in the properties files of the generated maven project by the custom archetype with the username.

Comment: I tried to give you a chance to find out the names of all properties, thereby finding the property you are searching for.

Comment: thanks for that. But all those properties do not seem to be available with the maven archetype. As i mentioned in the question, I have already tried ${user.name}, but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current username you could try the following:

```
<requiredProperty key="username">
    <defaultValue>${package.getClass().forName("java.lang.System").getProperty("user.name")}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```